# How to view a list of files from a file as an image gallery?

Tags: files, images, image-viewer

I have a txt file I created with `find` with the path of many files in different locations, separated by a newline. I want to navigate through these files like an image gallery, preferably with thumbnails. I can turn the newlines into spaces and the  absolute path if necessary.

I couldn't find an appropriate application or the right options to read that txt file, or I just don't know how to pipe/pass the file correctly. I tried with `xviewer` and `geeqie` already.

My last resource I want to avoid is to just symlink everything inside the same folder and use `xviewer` to navigate through it.

There should be a way to do this with some app, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I can get is `feh`, in Debian based distros:

```
$ sudo apt install -y feh
```

The you pass your file list as argument of option `-f` with the thumbnail option `-t`:

```
$ feh -tf list.txt
```

It opens a window with the thumbnails of the list of files, that you can navigate with the keyboard and the mouse.

Once an image is selected press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to render it, and <kbd>x</kbd> to close the opened image window.

More info in `man feh`.